# Cannot save existing entity with navigation properties in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-6.0

I have a project in .NET6 where I have a domain entity/AggregateRoot (ScoreCard) with a method to add more child entities (ScoreCardIndicator) that is a Navigation Property and also an entity. Below is just a snippet how I add the ScoreCardIndicators to ScoreCard on the domain model;

```
        public void AddScoreIndicators(List<ScoreIndicatorId> scoreIndicatorIds,
            List<ScoreCardPointsMetricData> scoreCardPointsMetricData)
        {
            // some code omitted for brevity

            foreach (var scoreIndicatorId in scoreIndicatorIds)
            {
                // omitted for brevity

                var scoreGrid = scoreCardPointsMetricData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ScoreIndicatorId == scoreIndicatorId.Value)
                        .IndicatorMetrics
                        .Select(x => new ScoreGridData(x.ScoreIndicatorOptionId, (float?)x.MinValue, (float?)x.MaxValue, x.Point))
                        .ToList();
                _scoreCardIndicators.Add(ScoreCardIndicator.Create(scoreIndicatorId, Id, scoreGrid));
            }

            _dateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

But when SaveChanges() is called, the following exception is thrown

> The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually
> affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since
> entities were loaded. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on
> understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I know that the error is because of the new entity added but it's only a join table that is as a result of a Many to Many relationship between ScoreCard and ScoreIndicator entities. Even when I mark the ScoreCard entity has Modified, EF still doesn't let it save successfully. I really do need to know what I'm missing.

For more information, I'm using the Code-First approach in EF-core. And the Entity mapping configuration for the said entities is as follows

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ScoreCard> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("ScoreCards");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

    builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
    builder.Property<string>("_name").HasColumnName("Name");
    builder.Property<string>("_description").HasColumnName("Description");
    builder.Property<string>("_institutionCode").HasColumnName("InstitutionCode");
    builder.Property<DateTime>("_dateCreated").HasColumnName("DateCreated");
    builder.Property<DateTime?>("_dateUpdated").HasColumnName("DateUpdated");
    builder.OwnsMany<ScoreCardIndicator>("_scoreCardIndicators", x =>
    {
        x.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("ScoreCardId");
        x.ToTable("ScoreCardIndicators");
        x.HasKey("ScoreIndicatorId", "ScoreCardId");
        x.Property<ScoreIndicatorId>("ScoreIndicatorId");
        x.Property<ScoreCardId>("ScoreCardId");
        x.OwnsMany<ScoreGrid>("_scoreCardMetrics", x =>
        {
            x.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("ScoreIndicatorId", "ScoreCardId");
            x.ToTable("ScoreCardGrid");
            x.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            x.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
            x.Property<ScoreIndicatorId>("ScoreIndicatorId");
            x.Property<ScoreCardId>("ScoreCardId");
            x.Property<ScoreIndicatorOptionId>("ScoreIndicatorOptionId").IsRequired(false);
            x.Property("_minValue").HasColumnName("MinValue");
            x.Property("_maxValue").HasColumnName("MaxValue");
            x.Property("_points").HasColumnName("Points");
            x.Property("_dateCreated").HasColumnName("DateCreated");
        });
    });
}
```